# Как сохранить значение "value" тега в поле "value" внутри объекта? Сериализуемый C #

Tags: c#, html, serializable

Делаю интерпретатор html тегов элементов форм Windows по университетскому заданию.

Нужно сохранить значение тега `tr` в поле `value` объекта `tr`.

C# code:

```
[Serializable]
class Table
{
    [XmlElement("tr")]
    public TrTable tr { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
class TrTable
{
    //????
    public string value { get; set; }

    //other tags inside "tr"
    [XmlElement("p")]
    public List<string> p { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("input")]
    public List<Input> input { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("img")]
    public List<Img> img { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ul")]
    public List<UlList> ul { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ol")]
    public List<OlList> ol { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("table")]
    public List<Table> table { get; set; }
}
```

Html code:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      value
      <input type="text"/>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Навесьте на `value` атрибут [XmlText](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmltextattribute?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Формировать так html - это извращение.